# How to split my bootstrap table in half and put one above the other?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, media-queries, tabular

I'm using bootstrap and I have a this kind of table:

```
| Label 1 | Value 1 | Label 2 | Value 2 | 
| Label 3 | Value 3 | Label 4 | Value 4 | 
| Label 5 | Value 5 | Label 6 | Value 6 | 
| Label 7 | Value 7 | Label 8 | Value 8 |
```

But on low resolution (i. e. mobile) I'd like to see something like that:

```
| Label 1 | Value 1 | 
| Label 3 | Value 3 | 
| Label 5 | Value 5 | 
| Label 7 | Value 7 | 
| Label 2 | Value 2 | 
| Label 4 | Value 4 | 
| Label 6 | Value 6 | 
| Label 8 | Value 8 |
```

Or like even better, like that:

```
| Label 1 | Value 1 | 
| Label 2 | Value 2 | 
| Label 3 | Value 3 | 
| Label 4 | Value 4 | 
| Label 5 | Value 5 | 
| Label 6 | Value 6 | 
| Label 7 | Value 7 | 
| Label 8 | Value 8 |
```

I know how `@media` queries work but I have know idea how to make this "split".

Could you help me?

Comment: Are you using an actual `<table>` element for this table or using general elements like `<div>`?

Comment: @DavidCarek Indeed I'm thinking about a full redesign of the table for divs. But the code actually use some css specific to tables and a row has a fixed height which is really useful for my needs. I know I can do it with div but it's a bit annoying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to use `<div>` elements bootstrap's `col` and `row` classes should be able to help.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6>
                Label1
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6>
                Value1
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6>
                Label2
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6>
                Value2
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Its not a very pretty option but it will wrap like the second 'prefered' option you want. The outermost row is one row in the table. The first option can be achieved with 2 tables each inside their own bootstrap columns.